# Jquery: Adding multiple values to textboxes (round two)

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

I don't think I explained myself as best I could [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393979/simple-jquery-adding-multiple-values-to-textboxes), so I'm going to give it another shot. From the following code:

```
<div id="addons" class="grid_12 omega">
    <div class="addon"> 
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="addon_1" value="addon_1"></span>
        <span class="title">Title 1 here</span>
        <span class="cost">$<em>49</em></span>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="addon"> 
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="addon_2" value="addon_2"></span>
        <span class="title">Title 2 here also</span>
        <span class="cost">$<em>95</em></span>
        <p>Some more text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="summaries" class="hidden">
        <input type="button" id="totalme" name="totalme">
        <input type="text" value="" id="addons_titles" name="addons_titles"><!-- item titles array, from addons that are checked  -->
        <input type="text" value="" id="addons_cost" name="addons_cost"><!-- total cost, from addons that are checked -->
    </div>
</div>
```

For all "**input[type=checkbox][checked]**" (checked addons), I'm trying to:

- summarise the titles from "**.addon .title input[name]**" to **input#addons_titles** (each title separated by pipe characters - eg: "Item 1 title | Item 2 title")
- and total item costs from "**.addon .cost em**" to **input#addons_cost**

I think the code given previously by [Obalix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393979/simple-jquery-adding-multiple-values-to-textboxes/2393999#2393999) and [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393979/simple-jquery-adding-multiple-values-to-textboxes/2394041#2394041) are on the mark,  I'm just not sure how to edit it to only do it for selected addons.

Also I'm not sure how to trigger this. I'm assuming I should run this on a submit button so the array is only created once - otherwise titles could be continually added to an ever duplicated array?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is more clear now.

This will work for your requirements:

```
$('#totalme').click(function () {
  var items = $('input:checkbox:checked'), // checked elements
      titles = [], // store the selected titles
      totalCost = 0; // store the total cost

  items.each(function () { // iterate over the checked elements
    var addon = $(this).closest('div.addon'), // get the closest div.addon
        title = $('span.title', addon).text(), // get title 
        cost = +$('span.cost em', addon).text(); // get cost coerced to number

    titles.push(title); // add the title
    totalCost += cost;  // add the cost to sumarize
  });

  $('#addons_titles').val(titles.join('|'));//join all titles with | as separator
  $('#addons_cost').val(totalCost); // show the amout

});
```

Check a live example [here](http://jsbin.com/ibadi/4/).

Comment: Awesome - thanks for putting it together in an example I can understand. One more question - how can I add the "#course_cost" to the totalCost? Example: http://jsbin.com/ibadi/6

Comment: +1 b/c I never even pondered the possibility of a :checkbox selector. Always do the long form.